# how to access the requesting user's data in firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

in my firestore, i have a boolean field called `admin` for the user documents in my users collection. when true, that user can read other user accounts. but how can i access that field in firestore.rules?

this doesn't work, but gets the idea across of what i am looking to do

```
allow get: if request.auth.uid.data.admin == true
```

the only data i see accessed in the documentation, is fom the resource being accessed. which would mean each user would have an `admins` array of every admin referenced in it, which would be a nightmare to maintain

Comment: Please edit the question to show both the set of rules, your database contents, and the actual query.  Rules are not meaningful unless there is query to go along with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to [use data from another document than the one that is being read](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents). If you have a `/users` collection with a document for each user stored under their UID, then:

```
allow get: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true
```

So this gets the user's document, and then check if there's an `admin` field in there that has the value of `true`.

Comment: yes! this is exactly what i need. and thank you for the link... who knows how many times i scrolled past that. and thank you @andresmijares for the function approach.. that will be super useful

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function isAdmin(request, uid) {
   return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true
}

match /YOUR_COLLECTION/{doc} {
   allow read: if isAdmin(request)
}
```

assuming you re using the uid as user doc id, this would work not only for user by collection you set this function